# The measures which are non-negative on all convex non-negative functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, convex-cone, borel-measures

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ (vectors with non-negative coordiantes), and let $M$ be the set of regular Borel measures with finite variation on $X$ and finite first moment: $$M:=\{\mu;\ |\mu|<\infty,\int_X|x|\text{d}\mu<\infty\}$$

What can be said about the measures in $M$ that satisfy $\int_Xf\text{d}\mu\geq 0$ for all $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and are:

- non-negative.
- continuous.
- convex.
- with bounded partial derivative that exists almost everywhere.

(Notice that such a function is always $\mu$-integrable since it is dominated by a linear function outside a compact subset),

Clearly, every non-negative measure belongs to $M$, but what other measures may be in there?

Comment: On a general metric space, you do not have convex functions.

Comment: I ask about metric spaces which are also vector spaces, or convex subsets of a vector space.

Comment: By "assigning value" to a convex function $f$ I am assuming you meant $\int_X f d\mu$. What kind of assumptions do you have on the space $X$ and the family of measures $\mu$ so that all (real valued, I presume?) convex functions on $X$ is integrable?

Comment: You are right. I need to clarify the question, I will edit it.

Comment: @MOMO You probably also need that $\mu$ is of finite total variation else $\mu$ can have a singularity at $x=0$ and not every convex function is integrable.

Comment: Again you are right. Edited.